# Can templates such as boost::mpl::integral_c be registered with Boost.Typeof?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, typeof

`boost::mpl::integral_c` is declared as:

```
template <typename T, T N>
struct integral_c;
```

Is it possible to register this sort of template with Boost.Typeof:

- For any `T`?
- For some `T`'s?

Answer (score 0):

N is a template parameter so it can only be a numeric type, therefore it only allows numeric types of T, the sort for which you can have template parameters.

Note that template parameters can be member pointer-to-function types or member pointer-to-data types but these are also considered types.

Comment: You can also pass in reference types, at least in MSVC, provided that it fits the other requirements for being a template parameter and a few others.